# BitBucket repo has file which is not in my src folder

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I used to have a java package called "Utils" and I renamed it to "utils" (uncapitalized) but it's still in the BitBucket repo. I tried to remove it using git by executing this command: "git rm src/me/lordal/gom/dtv/Utils/" but it says "fatal: pathspec 'src/me/lordal/gom/dtv/Utils/' did not match any files". So it's not in my src folder but it's still online on BitBucket.

As you can see here it has the "Utils", "Listeners" and the "Game" package two times but on the one capitalized.

[image]

Comment: did you commit/push the rename operation? what does git status says?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git does not do well with differences in capitalization of file names. You will need to specifically inform git that you changed the file name.

Two solutions to this problem can be found [here](http://nova-fusion.com/2011/08/31/changing-filename-case-in-git/)

The first is to rename the file to some completely different name `Ut-ils` for example (using `git mv`) then change it to `utils`.

The second is to use `git mv -f Utils utils`

---

To fix the problem, changing the name of `utils` to an intermediate name then running `git rm Utils` (you may need to specify `-r` due to recursion. (The name change is necessary to make sure that git does not try to remove the proper file.)

It may be worth doing this on a fresh clone of the repo.

Comment: If this comment worked for you please vote for it and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this then do the steps below.

`git -rm -r Utils/`

**on your local repo**

- `git add -m` // adds all the stuff you want to commit
- `git commit -m "updated util name"`
- `git push origin master (or whatever your branch name)`

This will update the bitbucket.